# Trying to rig a model, and parts are being stretched when moved

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm trying to rig my first model and when I move the fingers, they stretch to an insane amount, [image: here's an example photo since this website doesn't allow videos]

Answer (score 1):

As we see in your picture you've scaled your armature, you need to apply the scale with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode.

Comment: You need to do that in Object mode.

Comment: Thanks i've added the precision